# Simulate mouse click on MacOS second screen

Tags: c++, swift, macos, mouse, simulate

I try simulating programmatically mouse click on macOS, using C++/Swift. My below code works fine for the primary screen. However, I want to do similar for the secondary screen too.

Any idea how to do? Thanks

Test code in Swift (remember to link ApplicationServicess.framework):

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

let kDelayUSec : useconds_t = 500_000

func moveMouseClick(p: CGPoint) {

    let mouseMove = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: CGEventType.leftMouseDragged, mouseCursorPosition: p, mouseButton: CGMouseButton.left)
    let mouseDown = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: CGEventType.leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: p, mouseButton: CGMouseButton.left)
    let mouseUp = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: CGEventType.leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: p, mouseButton: CGMouseButton.left)

    mouseMove?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)

    usleep(kDelayUSec)
    mouseDown?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)

    usleep(kDelayUSec)
    mouseUp?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
}


print("Test mouse click")

let pointX = 300
let pointY = 200

let p = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(pointX), y: CGFloat(pointY))
moveMouseClick(p: p)
```

Comment: Just an idea: get the bounds of the screen with `CGDisplayBounds()` and calculate the location.

Comment: The `pointX` and `pointY` you are using to create your CGPoint `p` is most likely returning a point on the primary display. Have you tried changing those values to represent a point on the secondary display? Have you tried calling `NSScreen.screens[1].frame` to return the size of the secondary display? Maybe you can use that to replace the values for your `pointX` and `pointY`.